# Deleting one instance from data set in java

Tags: java, instance

I have data set contains one instance with "NAN" and i want to remove this instance in case it may affect the performance of my classifier. so I use the following code but it cant remove this instance.

The dataset looks like the following

```
{{[1,2,1,4,2,5,];1},{[2,3,1,6,5,8];2},{[1,4,3,6,9,2];1},{[NAN,NAN,NAN,NAN,NAN,NAN];class},{[1,3,4,7,8,6];2}]
```

The code that was used

```
       Dataset[] folds = data.folds((10), new Random(100));
        Dataset training = new DefaultDataset();
        Dataset testing = new DefaultDataset();
        int[] tr = {0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9};
        int[] te = {1, 4, 7};   // 7, 4 and 6,5 changes
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            training.addAll(folds[tr[i]]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            testing.addAll(folds[te[i]]);
        }

        int numFolds = 10;
        Dataset[] foldsTrain = training.folds(numFolds, new Random(1));

    for (int i =0; i < training.noAttributes()- 1 ; ++i) {
        //Instance inst = training.get(i);
        if (training.instance(i).equals("isNaN")) {
            training.remove(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Currently your list contains arrays several dimensions deep, and a single "for" loop cannot step into each of them. If you are on Java 8 or higher, maybe you can use the .stream().flatlist() method? Otherwise you'd need several loops.

Comment: I misread the label on the post, and desided that it refers to javascript and not java. You should have pointed that out when I posted a reference link to javascript. Nonetheless sorry for the confusion